# MOLDEN file from ORCA output

Tags: orca, molden

I'm trying to convert an ORCA output file into MOLDEN file (via molden itself).

I hit the "Write" button and it converts the file, yes, but the *displacement vector* s are zeros. I need that information in that specific file formatting.

What can I do?

Comment: I think you can use `orca_2mkl` tool (provided with Orca) to get molden files from Orca. What kind of displacement vector do you need? Is this for vibrational modes?

Comment: @SRMaiti yes I need vibrational modes. I tried that plugin, but it does not convert also the vibrations.

Comment: It would help to know what version of Orca you're using. My suggestion would be to use another tool. I don't know if `cclib` supports Molden vibrations, but that would be my suggestion. Even if not, it wouldn't be hard to write some Python to write `cclib` vibrations in Molden format.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the vibrations in Molden format?

Comment: @GeoffHutchison is ORCA 5.0.3. cclib does not support this version yet. I need it to pass it in another script in order to prdoce an wigner ensamble

Comment: Yeah, Orca 5 changed their formatting a lot, so I don’t think you’re going to get there at the moment without some coding. I’d still suggest working with the cclib team.

Comment: @AndreaPellegrini did you get an answer to this now? Perhaps you wrote some code to do it yourself? Please update us! :)

Comment: Not yet, unfortunatelly. Guys of `cclib` are still working.

Comment: @AndreaPellegrini the CCLIB developers are working on this?

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes they do

Comment: @AndreaPellegrini could you please add details such as a sample input file, sample output with missing output and also expected output ?